# Alternatives for PHP / cURL Cookies?

Tags: php, caching, curl, cookies

Are there **any alternatives** with PHP / cURL **without cookies cache on the server** like using a .txt file in the cURL Options CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE?

I tried to read the cookies from the HTTP header of the CURL session and to set them manually to avoid a server-side store here for the CURL session.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the headers directly.

```
$cookies = array(
    'somekey' => 'somevalue'
);
$endpoint = 'https://example.org';
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$timeout = 30;

$headers = array(
    sprintf('Cookie: %s', http_build_query($cookies, null, '; '))
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // you may need to make this false depending on the servers certificate 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $requestMethod);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

// now all the headers from your request will be available in $header
```

Comment: But I get the to be sent cookies from the response headers of cURL session.

Is it possible to get the header in the output and send along the cookie from this header in the next cURL session?

Comment: The function http_build_cookie(...) is undefined in my IDE. Which problem happend here?

Comment: I updated the function perhaps that will work for you instead.

Comment: But the cookies are set only in the PHP script from the cURL session and used again in the next call to a cURL session. How do I resolve this?

Currently, I read the cookies set from the response header of cURL session and put them in the browser with setcookie () and in a variable.

Comment: perhaps I'm not fully understanding. So you want to keep the cookies from request to request? perhaps make use of session variables rather than storing it on the client side.

Comment: Is it possible to set in the array $cookies also path, domain, Expires/Max-Age, etc. and send it in the HTTP header of the cURL session?

Comment: yes, just add them to the $cookies array more info is here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/

Comment: Should I add them like this array? $cookies = array( 'somekey' => array( 'value' => 'somevalue', 'path' => 'somepath', 'domain' => 'somedomain, ... ));

Comment: If I want to send all cookies which are setted in $ _COOKIE, do I have to send any cookie settings as expire, path, domain, etc. in the HTTP header of the cURL session or do cURL sends automatically these settings?

Comment: it will not automatically send these you will need to add them to the curl yourself, as well the $_COOKIES global will not tell you the expiration date, domain or path it simply exposes cookies which are valid for th current request.